# Output is not coming correct format in html

Tags: python, urllib2

Below code is working fine.

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
url = ['https://www.google.com/digitalworld/check_status/valid/next','https://www.yahoo.com/digitalworld/check_status/valid/next']
for i in url:
    req = Request(i)
    try:
        response = urlopen(i)
    except URLError, e:
        if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
            st = 'We failed to reach a server. Reason: ', e.reason
            ck2 = '{0},{1}'.format(i,st)
            print ck2
        elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
            st1 = 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request. Error code: ', e.code
            ck1 = '{0},{1}'.format(i,st1)
            print ck1
    else:
        st2 = 'URL is good!'
        ck = '{0},{1}'.format(i,st2)
        print ck
```

But the output is coming like below not in single line. Not sure problem with URL length

```
https://www.google.com/digitalworld/check_status/valid/next
,URL is good!
https://www.yahoo.com/digitalworld/check_status/valid/next
,URL is good!
```

can some please guide and how to bring in the same line.

Comment: 1. Is the line `response = urlopen(i)` meant to read `response = urlopen(req)`?

2. Where is the URL being printed?

Comment: @IronFarmb forgot to add

Comment: @Victory all the request and exception handlin part is irrelevant - you could have simplified the snippet to a proper MCVE like this  https://gist.github.com/BrunoDesthuilliers/378af2aac475965852996f0b74da0b40

Comment: Removed the HTML tag - there's absolutely nothing HTML-related here.

Comment: @Victory executing you code on my computer I __of course__ have no line wrap, at least unless I shrink my xterm's window to less than 72 characters (the length of the first string). What you see here (we don't know where since you didn't bother documenting how you're running that code nor where those strings get printed, but anyway) is "whather is displaying those lines" wrapping them so you can see the whole line. IOW 1/ the "issue" is outside Python and 2/ there's actually no issue at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no issue at all here.